# IOS 7 Xcode tabbar controller with 2 table views how to program XIB or storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I would like to know how I can extend a Tab Bar Controller and 2 table views with a new table view.

I have created an IOS 7 application with storyboard:

Tab Bar controller (with 2 tabs)

```
                         -> First View Controller with a Table ViewA

                         -> Second View Controller with a Table ViewB
```

Table ViewA shows an array of 16 items that are the sections of the array of 400 items. They are shown in a new Table View1

Depending on the section that is selected I want to show Table View1 positioned on the section that is selected (1 out of 16 sections).

The question: Can I add this table view1 via code or do I need to use storyboard?

Table ViewB shows also an array of 16 items that are the sections of the array of 400 items that I want to show in a new Table View2

Tab Bar controller (with 2 tabs)

```
          TAB1     -> First View Controller with a Table ViewA-> Table View1

          TAB2     -> Second View Controller with a Table ViewB-> Table View2
```

VIEW A shows the sections an array of 16 items, View 1 show an array of 400 items with

I want to be able to switch between the two TAB's on both views A and view1 and on viewB and view 2.
Has somebody an exemple to do this?

Comment: More than an answer, I would like to offer you a suggestion. Please check out the whole Storyboard topic. This is where you can outline the different scenes of your app. Using segues and the method prepare for segue, you can decide what the next tableView will display.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to determine which tableViewController to show in the 2nd "tab" or are you trying to add a 3rd tab?

Comment: I'm not adding a thirth tab, it's how to add a table view to the table view A and table view B.